# Issue in clicking next button in selenium-chromedriver

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-chromedriver

[my site](http://www.homesbrightoncolorado.com/cgi-bin/real?pge=newsearch&state=na&qsearch=true&allcities=Arvada%2CAurora%2CBennett%2CBrighton%2CBroomfield%2CByers%2CCommerce%20City%2CDenver%2CHenderson%2CHudson%2CKeenesburg%2CNorthglenn%2CStrasburg%2CThornton%2CWestminster&allcounty=Adams&cityupd=&action=&cord_n=&cord_w=&cord_s=&cord_e=&zoom_lvl=&allzipcodes=&allsubdivs=&price_lo=-1&price_hi=100000000&htype=ALL&saletype=A&tot_bed_lo=0&tot_bath_lo=0&tot_sqft_lo=0&year=&garage=0&acres_lo=0&style=&high_school=&jr_school=&ele_school=&sortby=price&property_type=1&area=&zipcode=&mlsno=&altqs=)

In Browse mode **my site** - clicking the next button its moving to next page.

By working with python-selenium-chromedriver **my site** its not moving to next page,it's show error.

```
driver.get(my site)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="goNext"]').click()
```

We also tried with firefox driver,it's not working..

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjwyh.png)

Comment: Why aren't you showing us the error that you get?

Answer (score 0):

you need to show the html of your browser, so that others can refer it to answer your question.

Still, I would suggest you to use [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/). Select xpath there and try putting `//*[@id="goNext"]` there and then press Evaluate button. Check if your 'Next' button gets highlighted. Also, verify at the bottom, it is showing 1 matching node. If your xpath does not matches, this will show `invalid xpath`.

And, if there are multiple elements in the html with same xpath, then it will show like `2 matching nodes found`. In that case, you need to go into the detail of provided xpath and make it granular using other attributes of the element to make it unique, so that it should show `1 matching nodes found`. 
Refer to the below given image for use of Firepath :-

[image]

Hope this helps you. But, still if you have issues, then please post your html.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
sleep_time = 3

driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH TO CHROMEDRIVER)
url=('http://www.homesbrightoncolorado.com/cgi-bin/real?pge=newsearch&state=na&qsearch=true&allcities=Arvada%2CAurora%2CBennett%2CBrighton%2CBroomfield%2CByers%2CCommerce%20City%2CDenver%2CHenderson%2CHudson%2CKeenesburg%2CNorthglenn%2CStrasburg%2CThornton%2CWestminster&allcounty=Adams&cityupd=&action=&cord_n=&cord_w=&cord_s=&cord_e=&zoom_lvl=&allzipcodes=&allsubdivs=&price_lo=-1&price_hi=100000000&htype=ALL&saletype=A&tot_bed_lo=0&tot_bath_lo=0&tot_sqft_lo=0&year=&garage=0&acres_lo=0&style=&high_school=&jr_school=&ele_school=&sortby=price&property_type=1&area=&zipcode=&mlsno=&altqs=')
driver.get(url)
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(sleep_time)
driver.find_element_by_id('goNext').click()
```

In your case the search results are not getting updated when you go to the url using chromedriver (beats me why). However when you simply refresh the page using driver.refresh(), the correct search results are shown and subsequently the next button works. Hope this helps.